# Android Multiple Animations

Tags: android, user-interface, animation

HI,
 When trying to show more than one animation at the same time sometimes one of the animations "hickups" and just seems to jump right to the end position.

What im trying to achive is have a Gallery baseed mebu that changes the current view in a ViewFlipper, the Gallery changes the current view on the setOnItemClickListener.
if i don't use the event to chnage the current view then my Gallery animation works as expected.

if i try to chnage the view then the ViewFlipper animation works but the Gallery animation is choppy.

Any advice as to the correct way for mutiple animations?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two `Animation`s and they are supposed to run at the same time and are grouped  together then you should combine them into an [`AnimationSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html). You can only do this if you have access to all the base `Animation`s. If you are using the built in `Gallery` animations then I'm not sure what you can do about it.

Comment: Thanks, though the animations run on two different views at the same time one is a view flipper and the other is the gallery, is it still possible to group them?